# How do I resize all of my ion-items in my ion-list to fit the entire screen in Ionic 3?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am currently coding an `ionic 3` mobile application and I am facing an issue with the `ion-list`. The `ion-items` inside the `ion-list` is not filling up the entire screen `(both width and height wise).`

**Here is a picture of my page:**

[image]

As you can see, the content is not filling up the entire `width and height`. I want it to start from the most `left side` and end at the most `right side` `(Same for up and down).`

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read documentation on ion-list [Ion-List](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/list) you need to set your style sheet properties in css files of your components [IONIC CSS Utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities)